# Jquery code works in chrome and FF, but not IE

Tags: jquery

I am using Chrome v32 and Jquery 1.10.2 . The below code works in all browser but IE78/9/10/
I haven't test ie 11. When used in IE, the Drop down div are not located at right place. It offcenter to right side.

```
var menuObjects = [];
var dropdowns = $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]')
$.each(dropdowns, function(index, value){
    var hoverButton = $(value);
    var dropdownDiv = $($(value).attr("data-target"));

    var o = {
        hoverButton: hoverButton, //The button that activates the dropdown
        dropdownDiv: dropdownDiv, //The dropdown menu itself
        flag: hoverButton.css("display") == false, //true = show, false = don't show/hide
        timer: null, //To be set in dropdownShow function
        delay: 400 //The default delay time           
    };

    menuObjects.push(o);

    //Add event listeners to both the button and the dropdown menu itself
    $(hoverButton).hover(
        function(){ dropdownShow(o, true); },  //over
        function(){ dropdownShow(o, false); }  //out
    );

    $(dropdownDiv).hover(
        function(){ dropdownShow(o, true); },  //over
        function(){ dropdownShow(o, false); }  //out
    ); 

});

/**
 * The dropdownShow timeout callback function -- if the mouse is not over either
 * the button or the menu then hide the menu, or if it is and it's hidden then show it.
 */
function dropdownToggle(obj){
    if (obj.flag && obj.dropdownDiv.css("display") == "none") {
        var o = obj.hoverButton.offset();

        //Use some default offset values if they are not defined in the object
        var dropdownY = o.top + obj.hoverButton.height() + 15;
        var dropdownX = o.left - obj.dropdownDiv.width() + obj.hoverButton.width()
        + removePx(obj.hoverButton.css("padding-left"))
        + removePx(obj.hoverButton.css("padding-right"));

        obj.dropdownDiv.css("top", dropdownY);
        obj.dropdownDiv.css("left", dropdownX);
        obj.dropdownDiv.show();

    } else if (!obj.flag && obj.dropdownDiv.css("display") == "block") {
        obj.dropdownDiv.hide();
    }
}

/**
 * Formats padding and margin values -- removes 'px' from the end and converts it to an integer.
 */
function removePx(el) {
    return parseInt(el.slice(0, -2))
}

function dropdownShow(obj, flag, hideDelay) {
    if (hideDelay == null) hideDelay = obj.delay;
    obj.flag = flag;
    if (obj.timer) clearTimeout(obj.timer);
    obj.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        dropdownToggle(obj);
    }, hideDelay);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just do this with CSS? That is what it is meant for.

Comment: because we are using asp and ajax. so the called hover divs can't be positioned inside hoverbutton as childrens

Comment: asp and ajax makes no difference, it depends on your markup. Obviously you can't position them inside, but they could be siblings, within a container element. It's difficult to tell without the HTML markup, and probably tough for anyone to help without it.

Comment: It is not markup problems. All browser except IE works.I just simply don't understand which jquery method is causing IE issue

Comment: Sure, I understand that. I'm just saying there are easier ways to achieve what you want. Good luck trying to get IE to behave, esp the older versions

Comment: You can actually use IE go to COMC.com and hover on cart button at top right corner.